# CSS height 100% with margin

Tags: css, height, margin

I am trying to display a div that has the same height as the browser window, but uses 200px margin at the top. So, at first I tried with height: 100%; but this does not work well with a margin because the div gets bigger than the browser window.

Then I tried that:

```
div {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  height: auto;
}
```

That works pretty well as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/fB9ea/1/

The problem is: If there is so much text that it gets bigger than the div, the text sticks out of the div, as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/fB9ea/

How can I fix that issue?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you need but here it might caused by position: absolute;

Comment: Sure it is caused by the position absolute. That is exactly my problem: I want a div (with a margin to the top) that is exactly as height as the page is, but it should get bigger when there is more text in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting 100% height to work is tricky to get right cross browser—and you have to do it on the outermost element. My suggestion would be to try something like the code below, where the `#wrap` div is set to 100% height of the browser window and contains a `.top` div 200px tall with the same background color as the body element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
html, body {
    height:100%;
} 

html,body {
    margin:0;padding:0;
}

#wrap {
    min-height:100%;
    background: red;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

* html #wrap {height:100%;}

.top {
    height: 200px;
    background: white;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap"> 
    <div class="top">
    </div>
    Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />Test<br />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! That is the only solution in that thread that covers both scenarios (few text, much text)!

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the absolute position of the `.div` check this fiddle:

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/fB9ea/2/)

I changed it to relative and added a width to it.

//EDIT//

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fB9ea/4/)

This can be done by min-height and max-height

//EDIT2//

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/fB9ea/7/) give the wrapper also a min-max height

[w3school explenation positions](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

Comment: Thats right. But the problem here is that the div get's not exactly as height as the site is, when there is few text: http://jsfiddle.net/fB9ea/3/

Comment: This can be done with min-height and max-height see  the updated awnser!

Comment: @charihans check it again. I gave the wrapper also a min-max-height

Answer (score 0):

How about using

```
overflow: scroll;
```

This will add a scrollbar to the div when the text gets too big, which I'm guessing is what you're after.

Comment: Nope, I want a div that is exactly as height as the site is, but it should get bigger when there is more text in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily fix this problem with `min-height`. This will make sure that your div is at least 100% the height of the page, but it will grow when there is more text. Your code will look like this:

```
div {
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dakoder/JHjkJ/

Comment: Nope not working: Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/JHjkJ/1/ The div is now 100%+20px height.